# How can I restore my deleted Google Account and how long before it is gone forever?

Tags: google-account, account-recovery

My account was hacked into and deleted just today (I know who did it because this person forced me to give them the password) because this person believes it is not safe for me to have this account, yet I am of the appropriate age.

I do not know if this account was temporarily deleted, but I am certain that Google does not have an option for that.

I am struggling to get it back since I have had this account for a long time and all of my information and saved data is there.

**How long do I have to recover my account, and what is the procedure to get my account back after it was deleted?**

Answer (score 6):

> If you [deleted your Google Account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32046), you have about 2–3 weeks to recover it. If your account is restored, you'll be able to sign in as usual to Gmail, Google Play, and other Google products.
>
> 1. Go to the [Account support page](https://accounts.google.com/signin/recovery).
> 2. Follow the instructions. You'll be asked some questions to confirm it's your account.

Source: [Google Account Help > Recover your Google Account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6236295?hl=en)